# NGINX default site works, but one on another port does not

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

Hello I am using nginx to set up two servers. one being a frontend port 80 and one being a backend port 8080 on one IP address.

The default one works, the backend through port 8080 gives me a Connection Timeout/ No response when trying to access the server.

I think it is my execution however, to test backend, I have a simple index.php that should come up if i go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 in a browser, except i get a connection time out / no response.

Nginx says it is open and listening. without the port number it goes to my frontend/default server for this ip address.

Error logs show nothing! Even the logs in my server blocks with access and upstream show nothing.

ubuntu 18.04

here is my config
server 1 port 80 default

```
   server {
  # Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
  listen 80 default_server;

  # Multiple hostnames separated by spaces.  Replace these as well.
  server_name www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com;

  root /var/www/my_project/html;

  error_page 404 errors/404.php;
#  access_log logs/my_project.ventures.access.log;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-upstream.log upstream buffer=16k;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-access.log combined buffer=16k;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

This is the second server that cannot be accessed via client.domain2.com or www.domain2.com - URL is correct, but shows server 1 htdocs instead. client.domain2.com:8080 or any other combination brings `Cannot reach site` or `Connection Timed out`

```
    server {
  # Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
  listen 8080;

  # Multiple hostnames separated by spaces.  Replace these as well.
  server_name client.domain2.com www.domain2.com;

  root /var/www/my_project/backend;

  error_page 404 errors/404.php;
#  access_log logs/my_project.fun.access.log;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-upstream.log upstream buffer=16k;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-access.log combined buffer=16k;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted nginx service after adding entry for 8080 port? Try disabling port 80 entry and adding default_server for the 8080 instead in the same fashion.

Comment: you probably could find 127.0.0.1:8080 open but not accessible on outer interfaces.  This is probably due to your firewall.

Answer (score 4):

you must to be allow your 8080 port in firewall

If you're not installed `ufw` install it like

```
$ sudo apt install ufw
```

Then check the ufw status

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

Check your needed port is added into the list.

then use

```
 $ sudo ufw allow 8080
```

then check the ufw status again. now it show you the allowed ipv4, ipv6 ports and connections. Restart your nginx server and check the port is working

```
$ sudo systemctl nginx restart
$ curl -I 'http://{youraddress}:8080'
```

Or hit the url in your browser.

If you are using GCP, AWS check the external firewall settings in your server console. like http_server allow 80. and edit this record to 80, 8080 and save it.

**Caution: Don't do the internal firewall settings using `ufw` in GCP, AWS** because already they have their own firewall settings for the engines.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration are correct. I maybe add "server_name" to each server.

You should add logging to each virtual host, adding this to each `server {}` entry:

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-upstream.log upstream buffer=16k;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-access.log combined buffer=16k;
```

You also need to add to your `http {}` entry to make upstream log works:

```
log_format upstream '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $request '
                    '$upstream_addr $upstream_cache_status $upstream_status $upstream_response_time';
```

You can check the requests logs at those files. Upstream log the transaction with PHP-FPM and access the HTTP request.

You could have some `iptables` block or other network limitation.

To check if your server are listening at port 8080, use this command as `root`:

```
bash# netstat -nap | grep -i nginx
```

This will show you something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:82              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/nginx: master p
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17513    939/nginx: master p
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17512    939/nginx: master p
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17518    939/nginx: master p
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17519    939/nginx: master p
```

In my case, NGiNX are listening at port 80, 81, 82 and 443.

To check you `iptables` rules, type:

```
bash# iptables-save
```

I'll not put here the output because it may vary a lot, and you just need to check the default `INPUT` rule (at top of output), like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [67342:4090666]
```

In my case, `INPUT` are default `DROP`. If you see an `ACCEPT` there, it's ok, otherwise you need to check if there's any explicit rule accepting packets at the port 8080.

If you've `INPUT` as `DROP`, you can test if this are your problem opening port 8080 with this command:

```
bash# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, everything seems to checkout from what you have stated. INPUT DROP is there and nginx is listening on the port numbers 80 and 8080. what should i do next?

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "upstream"` when putting `access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-upstream.log upstream buffer=16k;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/server.intra-access.log combined buffer=16k;` in conf

Comment: @zatyh Thanks for pointing the `upstream` log error. I forgot to add the log type declaration. I've edited the answer and added it. I'll also add information to `iptables`.

Comment: also, `sudo iptables` does not print up anything?

Comment: No, only if you got some error. Otherwise output nothing. You can check using `iptables-save` if command was accepted.

Comment: problem still persists, no errors coming up. the server I want to reach through port :8080 brings up my server in my seperate :80 server....seperate domains, default server on port 80 is default server. why is it doing this?

Comment: Are you using a separate network firewall or do all connections  go straight to your server? Are there any reverse proxies operating in front of your server?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your configuration, and it seems correct to me. Some things that comes to my mind that could cause the unexpected behavior you are experiencing:

- As others have said, did you restart nginx after creating the last conf file? I know it does sound silly but i forgot to do that myself a lot of time.
- Permission issues or wrong path for the `root` domain directive. Are you sure the www.domain2.com files directory exists and/or is readable by `www-data` / your nginx user?
- Check your DNS. Did you remember to add the www.domain2.com and other domain to your hosts file (assuming you are working on your own box, of course)? Are your domains reachable via ping or telnet?
- Try to validate your sintax, `sudo nginx -t`. Does it say something interesting?

Answer (score 1):

as you said:

> access and upstream show nothing

so the truth is elsewhere : look at your firewall. if you are using AWS, look at your VPC configuration (subnet, nacl, security group).

On nginx side, it seems fine, at least you must have a log access when pointing to index.php. If you want to see a log of your static files, you should comment the line

```
access_log off;
```

(only for testing, put it back from production).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact problem and as described in a comment above the reason was that the firewall was blocking the port